# Unit Test Project Not Able To Get Project Resource Files

Tags: c#, unit-testing

So I have an application that had a folder called SupportFiles. In that folder are some XML files the program uses for some function.

The files are loaded in the code like this:

```
var approot = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory;
var filepath = approot + @"\SupportFiles\SomeFile.xml";
```

When the app is compile it copies these files to the Release or Debug output folders.

When we first ran the tests, it could not find the files. We figured it was because it wasn't copying them to its output which according to the error was the TestReults folder. So the first idea was to simply copy the folder into the Test Project so that the test project would copy them to its output. But that did not work even with setting the files to copy if newer. And I don't think trying to access them the same way we do our test files using DeploymentItem will work.

We'd like to do this without refactoring the app code but if that is the only way we would appreciate suggestions.

And no. having them be an embedded resource will not work for us as we'd like to be able to just elevate the file if there is a change to the file that doesn't require a code change.

Thanks

Comment: Use Path.combine to concatenate paths

Answer (score 1):

Your assemblies will run from the unit test process you should try this.

```
using System.Reflection;
var approot = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
```